# Is there any way to prevent calling a specific function in certain part of code in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm currently working on implementing a module, which consist of three functions including `Init()`, `Process()` and `Release()`. And I'd like to find a way to throw compile error if using `std::vector::push_back` in `Process()` and `Release()` functions. Is there any possible way? Thank all!

```
class AModule {
 private:
  std::vector<std::int32_t> vector_list;

 public:
  bool Init() override {
    vector_list.push_back(10); // Allow to use push_back function only in Init state
  }
  void Process() override {
    vector_list.push_back(10); // Should throw compile error here
  }
  void Release() override {
    vector_list.push_back(10); // Should throw compile error here
  }
};
```

I have try using `static_assert` by wrapping the vector class, but it doesnt work properly.

Comment: encapsulation. Make `vector_list` a private member of a class and expose only the methods that should be accessible publicly

Comment: Init() should return a vector the parent class would save as a private member and offer protected member functions to _read_ the data from this vector.

Comment: Explain why you need `vector_list` as member field? As YSC suggested you can redesign API so this function are returning a vector (or accepting reference to it). This way `Process` will not see this symbol at all.

Comment: This does not compile. You cannot mark functions as `override` if they don't actually override a base class virtual function.

Comment: This kind of thing is called 'state orientation' and it was identified as a bad idea about 60 years ago.

Comment: @user207421 could you explain why this is a bad idea? Is there any possible solution instead of using state orientation. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `GCC` you can use the preprocessor to `poison` certain tokens after the `pragma` (see it live [here](https://godbolt.org/z/71qxEKedv)). If you are using `MSVC` then you can use the `deprecated` `pragma` to at least get a warning (which you can turn into a compile error by providing the correct flag).

```
// Header file
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

class AModule {
private:
    std::vector<std::int32_t> vector_list;

public:
    bool Init();
    void Process();
    void Release();
};

// Source file
bool AModule::Init() {
    vector_list.push_back(10); // Allow to use push_back function only in Init state
    return true;
}

// If GCC (and probably clang) 
#pragma GCC poison push_back // Please do not use this in a header file
// If MSVC
#pragma deprecated(push_back)

void AModule::Process() {
    // vector_list.push_back(10); // compile error here
}

void AModule::Release() {
    // vector_list.push_back(10); // compile error here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer its almost what I'm looking for. The `AModule` that I mentioned above is a derived class and I wonder if there is a way to force all derived classes getting error when using `push_back` in `Process` function. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks once again

Comment: Bad Solution: Put the `poison` `pragma` in the base class header. Actual Answer: No, anything you try to do to prevent me to `push_back` into my own `vector` when I derive from your base class, I can easily circumvent. If the `vector` is part of the base class, then you can make the `Process` function `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that `Process` is a `const` function.

```cpp
class AModule : public IModule {
private:
    std::vector<std::int32_t> vector_list;

public:
    bool Init() override
    {
        vector_list.push_back(10);
        return true;
    }
    void Process() const override
    {
#ifdef SHOW_ERROR
        vector_list.push_back(10);
#endif
    }
    void Release() override
    {
        vector_list.push_back(10);
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/e5GoEdvrY

Comment: What if `Process` does some calculations and stores the result in a member variable?

Comment: It depends on details which are not provided. With given data this solution is best.

Comment: What about `Release`? Given by the name of the function, it is reasonable to assume that this function does mutate the member variable(s).

Comment: `Process` Sounds like a member function which alter the data member. Therefore making it const doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @Const `Process` might return the result and not alter the data members. As Marek stated, the details of the functions are not provided. But you are correct, `Process` returns `void`, so without state modifications, this function is useless.